# Pandas - Efficient way for this?

Tags: python, pandas, filter, dataframe, multiple-columns

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe whose columns are ['a','b','c']. All of them are of type integers. I want to find the number of unique values in column 'b' corresponding to each unique value in column 'c' and store it in a new dataframe. How do I do that using pandas? I tried something like this:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for value in df['c'].unique():
    x1 = df[df['c']==value]
    x2 = x1['b'].unique().size
    new_df.append({'A': x2, 'B': value}, ignore_index=True)
```

but it takes too much time. Is there an efficient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this should work:

```
df.groupby("c")["b"].nunique()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('c')['b'].value_counts()
```

Comment: What it does is for each unique 'c', returns the count for each unique 'b' whereas I want for each unique 'c', returns the number of unique 'b'